# Not all strings from left join

Tags: mysql

I have this query

```
select delivery_first_week_repo.type, delivery_first_week_repo.from_sale, delivery_week_repo.from_sale
from delivery_first_week_repo
LEFT JOIN  delivery_week_repo on delivery_first_week_repo.type = delivery_week_repo.type
where delivery_first_week_repo.week_day = 'Tuesday'
and delivery_week_repo.week_day = 'Tuesday'
```

In `delivery_first_week_repo` there are some strings with type which is not in second table. But they are not displayed upon request.

Comment: show your table data with desired result set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When there's no matching row in the second table, the columns from the second table will be null in the join. So `delivery_week_repo.week_day = 'Tuesday'` will never be true for those rows.

Conditions on the second table should be put into the `ON` clause, not the `WHERE` clause.

```
select delivery_first_week_repo.type, delivery_first_week_repo.from_sale, delivery_week_repo.from_sale
from delivery_first_week_repo
LEFT JOIN  delivery_week_repo on delivery_first_week_repo.type = delivery_week_repo.type
    and delivery_week_repo.week_day = 'Tuesday'
where delivery_first_week_repo.week_day = 'Tuesday'
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because of the **LEFT JOIN** type.

using **inner join** will goive you the matching results

```
select delivery_first_week_repo.type, 
delivery_first_week_repo.from_sale, delivery_week_repo.from_sale
from delivery_first_week_repo
INNER JOIN  delivery_week_repo on delivery_first_week_repo.type = 
delivery_week_repo.type
where delivery_first_week_repo.week_day = 'Tuesday'
and delivery_week_repo.week_day = 'Tuesday'
```

Comment: `INNER JOIN` won't show the rows with no matches. He wants to see them.

Comment: His use of `and delivery_week_repo.week_day = 'Tuesday'` in the query makes his `LEFT JOIN` act like `INNER JOIN`, because it filters out all the non-matching rows.